# Can I install iOS 11 beta ipsw using iTunes without paying $99?

Tags: ios

I want to go for beta, but OTA updates are quite buggy, and on top of that, my phone doesn't see ota updates with beta profile installed.

So I found ipsw image about 2,4GB, that I can download. If I flash that rom via iTunes without enrollment of my Apple ID, will I be able to use that beta?

Comment: What do you mean by 'OTA updates are quite buggy'?  Is the beta corrupted when you do the download?

Comment: No, firstly, I can't download OTA at all — device doesn't show the updates available even with beta profile installed. Secondly, I don't really want to update via OTA, because it could lead to some bugs with Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, etc.

Comment: I would recommend **not** installing some random ipsw that you've found on the web.  Unless it's to a test device that doesn't have access to any of your other accounts.  If you've signed-up for the public beta but can't do the OTA upgrade, have you contacted Apple for help?

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking here, if beta ipsw officially available for installation via iTunes for non-developer users at all. • And no, I didn't contact. It's not such a big problem to do so =) Just wanted to know the answer for the initial question.

Comment: Although to address your “buggy” comment. iOS 11 Public beta 1 (developer beta 2) was incredibly buggy, so that might’ve been your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The free public beta program seems much safer and more reliable than trusting a download and/or needing to jailbreak.

- https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/